# Transparent listview in jquery mobile version 1.4

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I found many examples with version 1.3, but as far I see there is not working version for jqm 1.4

CSS solution on listview for version 1.3 was:

```
background-color: transparent !important;
background-image: url('') !important;
```

Can someone suggets me fix for version 1.4 (1.4.4)?

tnx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just apply it to the LI itself:

```
li {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

If you have anchor tags in the listitems, then apply it to the anchor:

```
li a {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/ek7L9fa8/)**

Comment: tnx, it's working..
I used listview in Collapsible, so I had to put transparent on .ui-collapsible-content and .ui-collapsible-heading class